# tcpdump whitelist filter for UPnP

Tags: tcpdump, upnp

How to capture **all** UPnP traffic with tcpdump? I’d like to use “white list” and to collect only UPnP traffic, not something else.

So have started and wrote this filter:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -nevvv -s 0 '(udp port 1900) or (tcp port 2869)'
```

Used following info from Wikipedia:

- UPnP uses UDP port 1900 and TCP port 2869.

How to elaborate the filter further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as that. SSDP (the discovery protocol) uses port 1900 (and apparently in some cases 2869) but the actual UPnP service can be on whatever port: SSDP is just a way to discover that port and other details about the service.

See [UPnP Device Architecture spec](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) (pdf) for more details.